# Ways to embed/upload a working 3D model onto a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model, 3d

I am looking to have a simple interactive 3D model on my site, like the ones on downloadable 3D websites but without all the watermarking and such. Does anyone have any suggestions or methods of doing so? I am also using Cargo as the server is providing a student discount.

tried embedding and uploading.

Answer (score 0):

[Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/) lets you embed models onto your website, if using an external site and paying to remove the watermark is not problematic to you.

Comment: Yes, and then some: [Sketchfab for Developers](https://sketchfab.com/developers)

Comment: Hi, I should've mentioned that I attempted the sketch fab option but even the student discount is at 100 a year, which is just out of my budget to load a 3D model onto my site. If theres any other sites that might be cheaper or less, please let me know!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).